# How can one loop in a ruby with 2 variables on Array

Tags: arrays, ruby, for-loop, tcl

In Tcl, if you have a list with even elements, one can loop two elements at a time. See this code:

```
foreach { a b } [ list 1 2 3 4 ] {
    puts "${a} ${b}"
}
```

Will output:

```
1 2
3 4
```

How can one get the same behavior with Ruby?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the same output by this way:

```
[1,2,3,4].each_slice(2) {|a, b| puts "#{a} #{b}" }
```

Comment: More generally: `[1,2,3,4].each_slice(2)  {|r| puts r.join(' ') }`

Comment: @tadman, sure, but my code is more similar with source code, so I've decided write exact by this.

Answer (score 1):

```
puts [1,2,33,44].join(' ').scan /\d+\s\d+/
1 2
33 44
```